# Streaming Invoice generate

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, flash-media-server, wowza

Is there any software available to calculate streaming usages (bandwidth, disk space etc.,) and generate invoice for the same as like [Ceiolometer](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Ceilometer) in OpenStack

I'm looking for a solution to generate streaming invoice, based on user usage

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [WMSPanel](https://wmspanel.com) for Wowza. The panel collects usage data and I use data export to process it separately in my billing system.
I need to create invoices yourself, but the data is accurate.
They also have billing calculation but it does not create invoices, I use it for reference only and for displaying data for my end-users via white label.

It's proprietary service though but it's a good option if you don't find open source solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Wowza Wrench](http://wowzatoolbox.com/wrench) can also cover partially your needs, at least the per user stream consumption, because it has pay-per-minute and pay-per-view features.